# Как заполнить коллекцию внутри объекта

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Имеются классы:

```
public partial class pr_abon : BaseEntity
{
    public pr_abon()
    {
        this.pr_receipt = new ObservableCollection<pr_receipt>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_a { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<pr_receipt> pr_receipt { get; set; }
}

public partial class pr_receipt : BaseEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_pr_abon { get; set; }

    public virtual pr_abon pr_abon { get; set; }
}
```

Как программно создать реляцию 1-M между `pr_abon` (PK `id`) и `pr_receipt` (FK `id_pr_abon`)?

Comment: почему через SqlQuery? чем недостаточно лямда выражений?

Comment: потому что используется фильтр данных. Если сначала получить список идов на клиент, а затем использовать .Where(w => selected_id.Contains(w.id)), на сервер уходит пакет:IN([через запятую 35 тыщ цифр]) и MS SQL захлёбывается с ошибкой

Comment: с какой ошибкой? у меня фильтры работают через `Contains` и все великолепно. Может стоит отследить почему ошибка? **UPD** не заметил про 35к Ids, вы уверены что фильтр нужно делать по такому количеству ID?

Comment: да, уверен, поэтому и выбран SqlQuery. работа в большими объёмами данных ведётся

Comment: кто мешает разбить Ids на диапазоны? если есть например непрерывные цепочки, то вполне можно использовать для фильтрации именно диапазоны, так оно быстрее будет и без всяких там ненужных в коде запросов SQL, а только Linq

Comment: EF для меня вновину и я просто не могу до сих понять - почему нельзя как-то в коде создать ту самую реляцию?! Или при работе с объектами просто так принято всегда самому дозаполнять данные?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно :) все очень даже просто, добавте в вопросе схему базы и какой запрос надо в итоге выполнить, я вам распишу как сделать через EF CodeFirst

Comment: var selected_id = Ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(flt_exp); //список идов
            XR_DataSource = new ObservableCollection<out_rm>(Ctx.pr_abon
                .Include(i => i.pr_charge_co)
                .Include(i => i.pr_devices_grp)
                .Where(w => selected_id.Take(10).Contains(w.id))
                ); добавил Take(10) - появилась ошибка переполнения стека

Comment: Вы видимо меня не поняли, необходимо обновить вопрос, в него добавить схему таблиц, связей и запрос который нужно выполнить по этой схеме

Comment: а здесь где-нибудь есть приватные сообщения? Боюсь, что буду лить много глупостей и неправильностей. Может стукнетесь в hreg666[at]inbox.ru?

Comment: ответ то все равно тут писать, опишите схематично, абстрагируйтесь от реальных данных, но сохраните саму суть, так что-бы из ответов было понятно вам, что делать и как

Comment: ну в вопросе как есть лёгкое описание: в out_rm есть коллекция pr_abon. В pr_abon - коллекция pr_receipt, которая в БД вяжется 1-М по ключу pr_abon.id->pr_receipt.id_pr_abon

Comment: в вопросе ваши попытки сделать велосипед, а необходимы исходные данные без "мусора"

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если используется Code First то нужно в контекст работы с базой добавить следующий код:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<pr_abon>()
   .HasMany<pr_receipt>(a => a.pr_receipt)
   .WithRequired(a => a.pr_abon)
   .HasForeignKey(a => a.id_pr_abon);
```

Comment: а если объекты просто вытянуты на клиента, материализованы и к контексту никак не привязаны?

Comment: @HellRiser используется DB First?

Comment: ага (и ещё символы, чтоб ответилось)

Comment: @HellRiser тогда надо обновить модель, при обновлении модели связи прописанные в базе перестроятся

Comment: @HellRiser как использовать DB First кратко описано тут: http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-for-beginners-creating-a-database-first-model/

Comment: я наверно как-то не так ещё осмыслил этот EF. В базе у меня все констрейны есть, мне необходимо на клиенте как-то проставить реляции между существующими порознь объектами. Такое возможно?

Comment: спасибо! ) А что если, как вы сказали, вытягивать пакетами? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467599/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-contains-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF

Comment: @HellRiser реляции между моделями можно сделать опираясь на описание по ссылке которую я дал чуть выше