# Как получить колекцию, используя Contains(), при большом количестве элементов списка

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

имеем на клиенте здоровый список (>35к шт.) ИДов:

```
var selected_id = Ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(flt_exp);
```

где flt_exp - заковыристый T-SQL. Например такой

```
SELECT ab.id 
FROM pr_abon ab 
WHERE 
    LOWER(ab.lc) LIKE '%0001568%' 
AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM houses ehs 
        INNER JOIN v_towns_pr_delivery etn 
            ON ehs.id_town=etn.id 
        WHERE 
            ehs.id=ab.id_hs_delivery 
        AND
            (
                (ehs.id_town='52032001000' AND ehs.title_short IN('1А'))
            OR
                (ehs.id_town='52032001000' AND (ehs.id_street='520320010000263')
            )
        )
    )
```

как надо написать условие в `.Where()` (и как разбивать selected_id) чтобы порциями выкачать данные с сервера в out?

```
        var out = Ctx.pr_abon
            .Where(w => selected_id.Contains(w.id))
            .Take(15)
            .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
            .ToList();
```

ошибка звучит так:

> Обработчик запросов исчерпал внутренние ресурсы, и ему не удалось предоставить план запроса. Это редкое событие, которое может происходить только при очень сложных запросах или запросах, которые обращаются к очень большому числу таблиц или секций. Упростите запрос. Если предполагается, что это сообщение получено по ошибке, свяжитесь со службой поддержки для получения дополнительных сведений.

Comment: 35 тысяч - это много? Поправьте вопрос - непонятно где вы что имеете, и что куда качаете, и для чего оно вам нужно.

Comment: а зачем Вы сначала на клиент получаете `Id`? что бы потом передать их обратно на сервер? может распишите поподробнее что Вам надо?!

Comment: потому что используется Ctx.Database.SqlQuery из-за того, что фильтрация на чистом T-SQL. Если можно как-то это в втиснуть LINQ - был бы признателен)

Comment: А какого типа `selected_id`? Почему бы вам не сделать обыкновенный Join?

Comment: но linq в итоге в тот же sql переводится, в чем преимущество _чистого_ T-SQL?

Comment: @Grundy смею предположить что тс просто не знает как это сделать, Автор опишите подробнее что Вы хотите сделать я думаю проблема решится

Comment: @VladD ввёл .Join(selected_id,
                    a => a.id,
                    j => j,
                    (a, j) => a) - получилось Необработанное исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException" в EntityFramework.dll

Comment: покажите ваш `flt_exp`

Comment: опишите структуру таблиц(например классом), укажите поля по которым необходимо соединить таблицы и условия

Comment: @Bald56rus есть сложные выражения по выбру данных с сервера, с операндами EXISTS, левыми, правыми, натуральными объедлинениями и прочее. Наработаны механизмы, как ткаие фильтры создавать в T-SQL. И далее нужно подучить данные на клиента, чтобы сформировать некие документы в больших количествах)

Comment: @Grundy ну например вот SELECT ab.id FROM pr_abon ab WHERE  LOWER(ab.lc) LIKE '%0001568%' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM houses ehs INNER JOIN v_towns_pr_delivery etn ON ehs.id_town=etn.id WHERE ehs.id=ab.id_hs_delivery  AND ((ehs.id_town='52032001000' AND ehs.title_short IN('1А'))  OR (ehs.id_town='52032001000' AND (ehs.id_street='520320010000263'))))

Comment: в пост его добавьте

Comment: `ab.lc` это строка?

Comment: ага. Но мне бы хотелось, чтобы запрос для фильтра оставался в T-SQL, а не портировался в LINQ

Comment: можете пояснить почему? :-)

Comment: потому что я в ужасе от того, что он на сервер шлёт ) Ну и опять же добавлю - есть куча наработок имеено с T-SQL

Comment: @VladD кстати .Join() тоже вышибается ошибкой уже при числе в 10к (

Comment: Тогда проще перенести все в хранику и просто дергать ее когда надо

Comment: @Grundy согласен, либо как вариант в мой запрос передавать ограниченное количество `Id`

Comment: Товарищи, а вообще EF умеет работать с большими объёмами?! О_о Извините за такие вопросы, я всегда работал с MS SQL и разными версиями FoxPro (от 2.х до 9) и никогда не было таких проблем (

Comment: а с чего Вы решили что дело EF?!

Comment: @Bald56rus потому что через Профайлер на сервер ничего не уходит. Ошибки переполнений на клиенте

Comment: судя по всему между тем как получили `selected_id` и использовании его в `Where` вы его материализовали - то есть выбрали данные в память, в этом случае естественно будет плохой вариант

Comment: секундочку уже пишу как бы сделал я

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31801/discussion-on-question-by-hellriser-----contains).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var skipTo = 0;
 var takeTo = 15;
 var out = Ctx.pr_abon
        .Where(w => selected_id.Contains(w.id))
        .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
        .Skip(skipTo)
        .Take(takeTo)
        .ToList();
```

будет получено первые 15 записей, если `skipTo` не равен 0 тогда будет пропущено указанное кол-во записей, т.е задавая количество пропускаемых метод `Skip` и получаемых `Take` выстраиваете логику получения данных

**UPD**

вариант №2

```
var ids = ;//здесь Ваши Id
var result = new List<T>(); //где T Ваш тип
int counter = 1000; //например подтянуть 1000 записей
for(int i=0; i<ids.Count();i+=counter;)
{
    if(i>ids.Count())

    var parts = Ctx.pr_abon
                   .Where(x=>ids.Skip(result.Count()).Take(counter))
    result.AddRange(parts);
}
```

пример [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oatezS)

Comment: Take() стоит после Where - на сервер ухидит 35к ИДов и ошибка

Comment: @HellRiser на сервер уйдет запрос в котором уже будет условие о необходимости получения только части данных. обновите вопрос: укажите ошибку которая у Вас возникает. и откуда на клиенте взялись `Id` записей которые необходимо получить?!

Comment: в Профилёре видно, что он посылает весь список

Comment: я так понял, можно выкрутиться нарезая сам selected_id на кусочки, а дальше сливать в коллектор полученные выборки. Только как это сделать, подскажите, плз)

Comment: @HellRiser обновил с простейшим примером, сори что так долго, отвлекли

Comment: ничтяк! Спасибо )